# how to avoid using DB converter tools using ORM and migrate DB easily

Tags: database, orm

I plan to use ORM in my project.

How should I approach DDL creation?

Is this all handled by ORM and i should use ORM CREATE objects for this?

Traditionally - I would create DDL scipt in plain SQL standard on hands, and move to another DB easily. But today there are many tools to create DB from Java classes or vice versa.

Point is: I don't want to get in trouble when I have to move to another DB and must perform manual DB column type conversion and similar things?

thank you very much for your time!

Answer (score 0):

its so easy ... you cant create orm class (or use many old orm ) and then change db name, only you must create class to migrate,

this class read all data from old db and write in new db with new structure

only i suggest read db structure, many db ( like noSQL db) have different structure.